# Problem with git log command when using git

Tags: git, github

I'm learning how to use Git and Github and I have a problem that the command git log I wrote in the terminal of VS Code but It didn't show all and it also appeared like the image I post below. Please show me what I should do, thank you!

[image: My problem]

Comment: It's showing the log inside a pager program, probably `less`. You can use the up/down/PgUp/PgDn keys to scroll :)

Comment: What exactly is the problem? It looks exactly like it's supposed to and shows your history

Comment: Just throwing this out there in case this is the question: Press the spacebar to scroll and the `q` character to quit out of that screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image itself is the answer.
Git log shows your previous commits, author info and timestamp of the commits